# Please help me understand this solution

Tags: probability-theory

> **Problem**
>   Let $\Omega$ be the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with the $\sigma$-field of Borel sets and $P$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Suppose that $\xi$ and $\eta$ are random variables on $\Omega$ with joint density $$f_{\xi,\eta}(x,y)=x+y$$ for any $x,y\in[0,1]$, and $f_{\xi,\eta}(x,y)=0$ otherwise. Show that $$E(\xi|\eta)={{2+3\eta}\over{3+6\eta}}.$$
>
> **Solution**
>   Since $$\eta^{-1}(B)=[0,1]\times B$$ for any Borel set $B$, we have $$\int_{\eta^{-1}(B)}\xi dP=\int_B\int_{\mathbb R}xf_{\xi,\eta}(x,y)dxdy$$
>   (The rest omitted.)

The above are an exercise and a part of the solution from Brzezniak, & Zastawniak. "*Basic Stochastic Processes*." pp. 25-26. I don't get two parts in the solution.

1. "$\eta^{-1}(B)=[0,1]\times B$."
2. "$\int_{\eta^{-1}(B)}\xi dP=\int_B\int_{\mathbb R}xf_{\xi,\eta}(x,y)dxdy.$"

For 1, I have no idea why it holds. For 2, I tried to apply the following theorem putting $h(x)=x$.

> **Theorem**
>   If $\xi$ has an absolutely continuous distribution with density $f_\xi$, then $$E(h(\xi))=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h(x)f_\xi(x)dx.$$

But I couldn't make it. Perhaps I need a generalized version of this theorem? Or maybe the theorem is of no use. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random variables $\xi$ and $\eta$ aren't explicitly defined. It appears that for the generic $\omega:=(\omega_1,\omega_2)\in\Omega$, we are defining
$
\xi(\omega) := \omega_1
$
and $\eta(\omega):=\omega_2$. That is, $\xi$ returns the first coordinate of $\omega$ and $\eta$ returns the second coordinate.

With this definition the assertion $\eta^{-1}(B)=[0,1]\times B$ is clear, because $\eta^{-1}(B)$ is the set of all points $\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2)\in\Omega$ where $\eta(\omega)\in B$, and $\eta(\omega)=\omega_2$ by definition.

For question (2), the Theorem you cited applies when calculating $Eh(\xi)$ for a real-valued $\xi$. Here you want $Eh(\xi,\eta)$ where the function $h$ applies to the pair of random variables $(\xi,\eta)$. You need a generalization of the cited theorem, which in this case would be
$$
E(h(\xi,\eta))=\iint h(x,y)f_{\xi,\eta}(x,y)\,dx\,dy.\tag1$$
To apply (1) to your situation, write
$$
\int_{\eta^{-1}(B)}\xi dP=\int_{[0,1]\times B}\xi dP=\int\xi I_B(\eta)dP=\int h(\xi,\eta)dP=E(h(\xi,\eta))
$$
with $h(x,y):=x I_B(y)$. Plugging this $h(x,y)$ into the RHS of (1) and simplifying will give you $\int_B\int_{[0,1]}xf_{\xi,\eta}(x,y)dx\,dy$.